# Injected nestjs service in to CQRS is undefined

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I have a service to import in CQRS but in runTime, I got an error for the service method

the service declared in constroctor and using it in excute methode

```js
@CommandHandler(UpdateSensorsProductsCommand)
export class UpdateSensorsProductsCommandHandler implements ICommandHandler<UpdateSensorsProductsCommand>
{
  constructor(
    private eventBus: EventBus,
    private sensorProductListService: SensorProductsListService,
  ) {}

  async execute(
    command: UpdateSensorsProductsCommand,
  ) {
    // I get this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAllSensorsProducts' of undefined
    this.sensorProductListService.getAllSensorsProducts()
  }
}
```

and I import the sensorProductListService module in my CQRS module called `SystemCqrsModule`

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    CqrsModule,
    SensorProductsListModule,
  ],
    ...
  exports: [CqrsModule],
})
export class SystemCqrsModule {}
```

and export sensorProductListService from sensorProductListModule

> this is sensorProductListModule

```js
@Module({
  providers: [SensorProductsListService, UnitConvert],
  exports: [SensorProductsListService],
})
export class SensorProductsListModule {}
```

so I have this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAllSensorsProducts' of undefined

why I get this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a `request` scoped within a class that is injected into your service, that's not going to work.

You should either remove `request` scoped dependency or handle it with `moduleRef`. See [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#request-scoped-strategies)